# Raspberry Pi: Sound Replay works with HDMI and omxplayer but not with Chrome Browser for youtube Videos

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian

The audio via HDMI for Youtube.com videos (played via the chrome browser) was working on my raspberry pi 4/raspbian until I started experimenting with a microphone for zoom meetings. ([This USB microphone seems to be working now.](https://raspberrytips.com/add-microphone-raspberry-pi/)).

Now, however, I can no longer hear any audio when playing youtube videos.

We can hear sound via the HDMI with this command:

```
  sudo aplay /usr/share/sounds/alsa/Front_Center.wav
```

I also discovered that I can record and playback sound (via HDMI) with audacity and omxplayer. This works:

```
 omxplayer -o hdmi hello.wav
```

I tried making HDMI the default:

```
amixer cset numid=3 2
```

This did not seem to help.

I was surprised I did not see my audio output. Should numbid=3 be the 'Mic Capture Volume'? I was expecting it to be the control for my HDMI audio.

```
amixer controls | sort
numid=1,iface=PCM,name='Capture Channel Map'
numid=2,iface=MIXER,name='Mic Capture Switch'
numid=3,iface=MIXER,name='Mic Capture Volume'
numid=4,iface=MIXER,name='Auto Gain Control'
numid=5,iface=CARD,name='Keep Interface'
```

uname -a says:

```
Linux raspberrypi 4.19.75-v7l+ #1270 SMP Tue Sep 24 18:51:41 BST 2019 armv7l GNU/Linux
```

Can anyone help me play you tube vidoes (with audio!) again via my HDMI port?

Thank you

Siegfried

Comment: I have the exact same problem (except that I have headphones using line-out)! And I am not able to figure it out. Can someone move this question to raspberry SE so that we can get more eyes on it?

Comment: Please give me a URL to move it to. Are you suggesting I just cut and paste to this other forum?

Comment: Here's some guidance: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2683/364132. We'll need to rely on reputed fellows of the SE empire to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Problem was mostly solved by re-installing raspberian OS.
HDMI Speakers and USB Microphone work for audacity sound editor.

HDMI speakers work with Chrome for YouTube.

USB Microphone still does not work for Zoom meetings. Has anyone got this working?

Thanks

Siegfried